# Cesium Cartesian3 move vertically up

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, cartesian, cartography

I want to move a [Cartesian3](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartesian3.html) position vertically up by `x` amount of units (e.g., meters).

**I DON'T want** to convert it to [Cartographic](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartographic.html), add `x` to the altitude and covert back to [Cartesian3](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartesian3.html).

**What would be the best way (performance-wise) to do this operation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super easy.

```
    const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(129.507780, 42.9075, 0);
    const origMagnitude = Cesium.Cartesian3.magnitude(position);
    const verticalAmount = 10;
    const newMagnitude = origMagnitude + verticalAmount;
    const scalar = newMagnitude / origMagnitude;

    const newPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
    Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyByScalar(position, scalar, newPosition);
```

Here's [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Comment: Hi @ZhefengJin, thanks! One more question. As I understand this wouldn't apply for X/Y direction. What if I want to move point X or Y direction? Can I achieve that with a similar logic?

Comment: when you say x, y-direction, at which coordinate do you mean? ECEF or local coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, moving directly away from the center of the Earth (as shown in another answer here) is nearly up but not exactly a perfect local up.  The reason is the Earth actually bulges a little around the equator due to rotation, and indeed the WGS84 ellipsoid (used by Cesium) is not a perfect sphere, it has the bulge included.  Moving away from its center gives you the "Geocentric up", but not the "Geodetic up" which is the true local up.  Admittedly, it's a very slight difference.

One way to find the proper local up is to ask for a local coordinate system from a given starting position.  In the following example, local up (as well as local East & local North) are calculated for a known position on the surface of WGS84.  A green dot is shown at the starting location, a yellow dot is shown above that, and a blue dot is shown to the East.  (West would be -X, North & South are +Y and -Y in this local frame).

[Sandcastle live demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

// Get the transform from local east-north-up to Earth Fixed at a known position.
var center = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-79.0, 40.0);
var transform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(center);

// Green dot at center
viewer.entities.add({
  position: center,
  point: {
    color: Cesium.Color.LIME,
    pixelSize: 10
  }
});

// Yellow dot 40 meters above
var above = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(transform,
    new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 40.0), new Cesium.Cartesian3());

viewer.entities.add({
  position: above,
  point: {
    color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize: 10
  }
});

// Blue dot 40 meters East (straight line East of center, not following Earth curvature)
var east = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(transform,
    new Cesium.Cartesian3(40.0, 0, 0), new Cesium.Cartesian3());

viewer.entities.add({
  position: east,
  point: {
    color: Cesium.Color.LIGHTSKYBLUE,
    pixelSize: 10
  }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```