# Cesium : Set height offset on SampledProperty with ClampToGround

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm using a sandcastle example to animate an entity by using SampledProperty and clampToGround methods. I want to add height distance between entity and the path on which it is moving.

I have tried the solution given on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69093213/14892726) But not getting any change on entity position.
Here is the sandcastle [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think `clampToGround` likely isn't compatible with adding a height.  You may have to fetch the heights from the terrain and include them in the SampledPositionProperty.

Comment: I think I got failed to explain the  requirement properly. I wanted to move object with clampToGround position but at given height.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by modify code as below:

```
function start() {
  clock.shouldAnimate = true;
  var objectsToExclude = [entity];
  scene.postRender.addEventListener(function () {
    var position = positionProperty.getValue(clock.currentTime);
    var clampPos = scene.clampToHeight(position, objectsToExclude);
    clampPos = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(clampPos),new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 2), new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    entity.position = clampPos;
  });
}
```

Sandcastle [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)